# Resize image from CSS

Tags: css, html

I am displaying a image from a json like this

```
<img ng-src= http://********/****/{{newsS.image}}>
```

And that image is too big,it takes all of the screen. I tried to scale it down using a div created in my CSS like this

```
#imgresize{
    max-width:25%; 
    max-height:25%;
}
```

I added my div to the image like this

```
<div id ='imgresize'> <img ng-src= http://*********.com/***c/{{newsS.image}}> </div>
```

But my image has not resized. I can i fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you apply the `max-width` etc. to the `img` tag, or give that an additional `max-width:100%`?

Comment: well first off, you should resize the image for the web.  not only does the full image load every time it is pulled from your server, but the bandwidth that you put out and people have to use is excessive. If you want to have a smaller size and a bigger size for say, clicking to view larger, than that is good.  However, you should follow development standards and have respect for your users and resize the image and saving a smaller size.  there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img ng-src= http://********/****/{{newsS.image}} width="300" height="500">
```

Try something like this and edit the pixels to what suits your needs

Comment: can i use % instead of px? if i can should i use them like this?
Ex: "25%"

Comment: Yeah that should be fine

Comment: i tried your method and i was able to scale down the images. But the problem is the images are not in same size. i want all my images in same size. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class for `img` tag:-

> img{ max-width:100%; }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try below CSS

```css
#imgresize
{
    width:25%; 
    height:25%;
}
```

It is working for me. Moreover, max-height and max-width property is used for last point of height and width after max limit element will be scrollable while simple height and width give the position of element.

Answer (score 0):

U need with img tag size value.

```
#imgresize {max-width:25%; max-height:25%;}
```

and

```
img {width:100%; height:100%}
```

Comment: Do you want use 2 divs ? Or 1 div in img tag use ?
İf you want use 2 divs 
`<div id ="imgContent"><div id="img"><img src="foo" /></div></div>`
**css** `#imgContent{max-width:25%; max-height:25%;} #img{width:100%; height:100%}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need this :

```
<img id ='imgresize' ng-src= http://*********.com/***c/{{newsS.image}}>
```

and

change css to :

```
#imgresize{
width:25%;  <!-- or width : 100px; -->
height:25%; <!-- or height : 100px; -->
}
```